# SQL Injection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection

I read something about SQL Injection in Rails, but things are pretty unclear for me. For example, I didn't understand if code like the one listed below is safe from SQL Injection or not.

```
User.where("first_name like ? ", "%#{params[:q]}%")
```

If not, what's the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. ActiveRecord will use a [prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) after sanitising your parameters to prevent SQL injection.

The Rails guides give more information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection

Comment: Can you explain me what's a prepared statement, please?

Comment: He interpolates it to add the `%` (wildcard).

Comment: @Madalina The database is told that there are a set number of parameters and what positions they are in. The SQL is then sent to the database with placeholders so whatever your parameters are, they cannot modify the SQL, which has already been set up. This prevents an attacker from putting SQL code into the parameters, which alters how the statement works. The examples on the Rails guide link show you how this is done.

Comment: Just saw you are using % for wildcards, so interpolation _is_ needed.